# IOS safari and Chrome block my websocket django Channels

Tags: ios, django, websocket, safari, channel

I’m having a problem developping my web app with django channels. On laptop, the websocket works perfectly: data are well received end sent. But on all iPhone, it does not work. Thanks to web inspector I caught the error: the connexion is blocked because it is not secure(ws). Same problem with IOS Chrome but  Ecosia works. The app works fine on Android. 
How can i prevent IOS safari (and Chrome) from blocking the connexion ?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Found by myself. I have to secure the connexion (https). In django/heroku I must add these 2 lines in settings.py

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True 
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

and create the Websocket constructor in my js file with a path 'wss://...' Now by websocket is secured.

Still don't know why IOS safari blocked the connexion with a ws websocket.

Be careful, these settings only work in production.